# iOS - Custom drawing on top of a background image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new to iOS development and just realized that drawRect will not be called for UIImageView. Is there another way to get around this? I am trying to draw a board game and I have an image I want to use as the background on top of which I was hoping to draw the board (squares). The idea being if its an image I can create it the way I want easily. All I need to do in that case is draw the squares. Is there another way to achieve this? Can I load the image as the background in a UIView?

Answer (score 1):

Add you image view to the main view. Then add your custom view on top of the image view. Your custom view should be a class that implements its `drawRect:` method and renders the squares as needed.

Comment: Sweet! of course! A view on top of a view. I am slowly getting into the mindset. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Some difference method:
1.in a view

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [yourImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 133)];
}
```

and `[self setNeedsDisplay]` this method can update the drawRect
2.`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UserDefault pathForImage:@"bg"]];`
this method can used view and viewcontroller
3.set UIImageView as subView on your super view, `[yourImageView setImage:@"imgaeName"];`